# get_posts of Custom Post Type AND Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to pull custom post types that have a specific custom taxonomy

This is what i've tried:

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'products',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'tax_query'         => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'subjects',
                    'field'     => 'name',
                    'terms'     => $shortcode_atts['subject'],
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'plans',
                    'field'     => 'name',
                    'terms'     => $shortcode_atts['plan'],
                ),
            ),
        );
```

$shortcode_atts looks like this:

```
string(80) "Array
(
    [subject] => אינטרנט
    [plan] => מסלול 10 גיגה 
)
"
```

i.e. That's in Hebrew, subject=internet and plan=10giga

I also tried to use operator, wasn't sure in which place to add it so I tried in all locations but it didn't work. Can someone guide me how to pull these posts?

This query returns all cpt's without the filtering that I want.

EDIT: shortcode_atts is this:

```
function show_product( $atts, $content = null, $tag ) {
    $shortcode_atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'subject' => '',
        'plan'  =>  ''
    ), $atts );
}
add_shortcode( 'show_product', 'show_product' );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question says `$shortcode_atts` is a string. It should be an array. Can you include more of where you're setting it.

Comment: I edited the post, do I need to set the values to `$atts['subject']` and `$atts['plan']`? the documentation for this method isn't so good.

Comment: No, what you have is correct. Can you `var_dump( $args )` and show what you get.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h3m64HeZ - It's supposed to get only post 1 and 2, not 0.

Comment: No, dump `$args`. Just the arguments, before you do the query.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zH16SMMr - I added the relation and operator attributes because i'm currently trying some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use multiple taxonomies at once, so use`'relation' => 'AND'`:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'products',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // this is what was missing
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'subjects',
            'field'     => 'name',
            'terms'     => $shortcode_atts['subject'],
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'plans',
            'field'     => 'name',
            'terms'     => $shortcode_atts['plan'],
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: That actually doesn't find any post, which is weird because your syntax looks correct.

Comment: Try to cast `'terms'` like `'terms' => (string) $shortcode_atts['plan']`.

Comment: It's a string originally, anyhow it doesn't work.

Comment: This is how everything looks: https://pastebin.com/HyAb9f34

Comment: How did you get it?

Comment: Get what? by the way, when I `var_dump($products)` I don't see the taxonomies, is this normal?

Comment: Yes, post object does not contain any taxonomies, also they are stored in different DB table. How did you get it working? What was the problem?

Comment: I didn't get it working :/

Comment: Nevermind, the query works, it was my bad. Thank you very much!